# Square numbers in list and then add them up

Tags: sml, ml

I am trying to create a function that squares the numbers of an ML list and then adds those numbers up

```
fun sqsum(lst) = map (fn x => x*x) lst;
```

What I have there takes a list and returns a list of the square of each number but I can't figure out the adding part.

Comment: Write a function `sum` that adds up the elements of a list without squaring them. Apply it to your squared list.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve one sub-problem at a time and compose the result:

```
val sq = map (fn x => x*x)
val sum = foldl (fn (x, result) => x + result) 0
val sqsum = sum o sq
```

Or you could fuse the `map` and the `foldl` together:

```
val sqsum = foldl (fn (x, result) => x*x + result) 0
```

Or you could write this function with a recursive definition:

```
fun sqsum (x::xs) = x*x + sqsum xs
  | sqsum [] = 0
```

And eventually improve it to be tail-recursive:

```
fun sqsum L =
    let fun f (x::xs) result = f xs (x*x + result)
          | f [] result = result
    in f L 0 end
```

Even though higher-order list combinators like `map` and `foldl` are immensely useful and improve the readability of code once you get used to them, solving introductory exercises using manual recursion is very valuable to the learning process; after all, `map` and `foldl` are built this way.